# Strange error: Undefined variable: css in /ImpressPages/Ip/Internal/Design/LessCompiler.php:69

Tags: compilation, themes, less, impresspages

Each time I am changing a something in the styles (e.g. inside less/variables.less) I get the known error in the front end saying:

```
Undefined variable: css in /ImpressPages/Ip/Internal/Design/LessCompiler.php:69
```

I can't find any error inside the files or in the linking nor are the rights set wrong.

My theme.less looks like this:

```
    //
    // ImpressPages theme: One Pager Crystal
    //
    // Main theme's LESS file. Contains only imports of required components.
    // Integrated with fluid and responsive grid system
    //
    // @package ImpressPages
    //

    @import "ipContent.less";// import system ipContent.less file (widget styles)
    @import "less/variables.less";
    @import "less/layout.less";
    @import "widgetOverride.css";
```

The less/variables.less looks like this:

```
    // Variables Grayscale Theme

    @primary: #0033ff;
    @dark: #000;
    @light: #fff;
```

What could be the problem? Isn't it possible to add own less files in a theme? 
PHPStorm shows the right colors inside my layout.less so the values from variables.less are matching correctly.

The user rights on my local system are all set to 775/775 for all groups, so thsi can't be my problem.

I am using today's build from github.

Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: I found out that the compiled css file gets 644 permissions which is not enough for the www group. 
This is strange as all folders and files have 775. 
I suppose that the css file is created but can't be filled with content, just with the comment not to edit this css file but the theme.less.
 
Can this behaviour be changed? I am running this locally under MAMP Pro (Mac OS X Mavericks).

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue which was already fixed but not released yet.

Here's a link to a fix - https://github.com/impresspages/ImpressPages/commit/c91d20d9bbf35702145bf18be028ab4882cbb2c6

Feel free to change the core file with this change or wait for an official update.

Comment: Thank you for the hint!
I think I'll checkout the Git repository regularly ;-)

Comment: Hm, that wasn't the problem.  
I checked the file and it was already changed like this. 
I am checking this out with MAMP Pro support but the coders are on holiday until Monday. 
Patience...